# Is there an API that returns consolidated metadata including layouts?

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api, metadata, user-interface-api

I believe I saw some information about a recent REST API that provided consolidated metadata including layout information. (For use by e.g. a mobile app that wants to base its screens on the metadata.)

But right now my Google skills to find this API are failing me (or perhaps I misunderstood what I read). Do you know of such an API introduced in the last year?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you might be referring to the brand-spanking-new UI API.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm

> User Interface API enables you to create native mobile apps and custom web apps with your own branding and look and feel. A single REST request returns enough metadata, layout information, and data to display, edit, or create a record.

Comment: I was just coming to post this. At least I know I found the right one too! lol

Comment: I'm sure I'll be hearing ALL about it at Dreamforce. :)

Comment: The GA version of the docs is here until next week, when the URL in the main post becomes the 210 version.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm

Comment: Also check out these sample apps:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/RecordViewerNative
https://github.com/forcedotcom/RecordViewer

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Salesforce tooling API to get complete metadata structure and can utilize it and render it in your app whatever way you want to have it.

For complete metadata, follow below document
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_tooling.pdf

Few quick examples are here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resource_examples.htm